# calculus continuity of a hard question?

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

How do i calculate the continuity of a function if the functions are in a given set limit. I tried doing it but I epically failed… Please help!how do I solve it?
When I tried to solve this I got that this function was not continuous but I'm not sure if it is right. Thanks!
$$w(t)=\cases{
     48+3.64x+.6363x^2, &   if $\ 1\le x \le 28$\cr
     -1004+65.8x      ,&   if $\ 28 \le x \le 56$}
$$
Thank you so much!

Comment: w(t)=
     48+3.64x+.6363x^2   if 1</= x </= 28
     -1004+65.8x         if 28 </= x </= 56

Comment: since polynomials are continuous everywhere they're defined, you'd just need to check to see if it's continuous where you put the "two parts" together (i.e., 28)

Comment: if i got 2339.2 for the first function at 28 and 838.4 for the second function at 28 does that mean that they do not connect therefore making it no continuous?

Comment: Is the function right? Note at $28$ one of the cases should have a strict inequality. But I edited according to your comment which seemed to say they were all non-strict.

Comment: well, i calculated a different answer for the first function, but you're right. since they don't connect, there is a jump discontinuity.

Comment: yes the function written was correct, double checked! :) 
okay ill try looking for the first answer again!

Comment: oops it was 648. 78

Comment: I think @DavidMitra is saying the intervals that define the domain in the two cases should be disjoint, but $28$ is in both "cases". You should probably have a "$<$" sign in place of a "$\leq$" sign in one or the other on the side where $28$ sits. Because the function will not be consistently defined if it *isn't* a match in both cases.

Comment: oh! I'm sorry you're right! the second one should be 28<x</=56

Comment: does that change my answer then?

Answer (score 0):

For limit for function f($x$) to exist at  $\lim_{x\to a^-}$ f($x$) = $\lim_{x\to a^+}$ f($x$) = f($a$).Here in this partwise(broken) function(at $x$=28),for function to be continuous limit should exist at $x$ = 28(as it is the breaking point). Now checking limit at $x$ = 28.$\lim_{x\to 28^-}$ f($x$) = $\lim_{x\to 28^+}$ f($x$) = f($28$).$\lim_{x\to 28^-}$ f($x$) = 648.78 and $\lim_{x\to 28^+}$ f($x$) = 83.84.and f($28$)= 83.84.Hence it is clear that $\lim_{x\to a^-}$ f($x$)$\ne$ $\lim_{x\to a^+}$ f($x$).Hence limit doesn't exist .So function is not continuous at $x$ = 28